# Get current slide bar value

Tags: angularjs

I was looking at

http://codepen.io/alexandercastillo/pen/JmBou/

```
<div class="progress-box" ng-app>
  <div class="percentage-cur" ng-init="selectedRange=0">
    <span class="num">{{ selectedRange }}%</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-slider">
    <input class="progress-slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" ng-model="selectedRange">
    <div class="inner" ng-style="{ width: selectedRange + '%' || '0%' }"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I was wondering how one would get the value of the slide after AFTER the user has released the left mouse click button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, the input type range updates the ng-model **selectedRange**.

Comment: Ahh yep you're right

    alert($scope.selectedRange);

shows the current value